# Bash difference or preferred negation statement

Tags: bash, shell-script, test

Is there a difference in bash, or a preferred usage of negation of a statement?

```
if ! [[ -z "${var}" ]]; then
  do_something
fi
```

Versus

```
if [[ ! -z "${var}" ]]; then
  do_something
fi
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
! [[ expression ]]
```

This will be true if the entire test returns false

```
[[ ! expression ]]
```

This will be true if the individual expression returns false.

---

Since the test can be a compound expression this can be very different.  For example:

```
$ [[ ! 0 -eq 1 || 1 -eq 1 ]] && echo yes || echo no
yes
$ ! [[ 0 -eq 1 || 1 -eq 1 ]] && echo yes || echo no
no
```

Personally I prefer to use the negation inside the test construct where applicable but it's perfectly fine outside depending on your intent.

Answer (score 5):

A `! cmd` is actually a **pipe**, and the `!` negates the exit code of the **whole** pipe.

From man bash:

> Pipelines
>     A pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by one of the control operators | or |&. The format for a pipeline is:
>
> ```
>          [time [-p]] [ ! ] command [ [|||&] command2 ... ]
> ```
>
> ...
>   If the reserved word ! precedes a pipeline, the exit status of that pipeline is the logical  negation  of  the  exit  status  as described above.  The shell waits for all commands in the pipeline to terminate before returning a value.

In that sense, a:

```
! [[ 2 -eq 2 ]]
```

Is the negation (`!`) of the exit code of the whole `[[` (once all of it has been executed). Thus, this has an exit code of 0:

```
!  [[ 2 -eq 2 && 3 -eq 4 ]]
```

#### However

A `[[ ! ]]` is a **Compound command** (not a pipe). From man bash:

> Compound Commands
>   ...
>   [[ expression ]]
>   Return a status of 0 or 1 depending on the evaluation of the conditional expression expression.
>   Expressions are composed of the primaries described below under CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS.

Therefore, this has an exit code of 1:

```
[[ ! 2 -eq 2 && 3 -eq 4 ]]
```

Because that is actually equivalent to this:

```
[[ ( ! 2 -eq 2 ) && ( 3 -eq 4 ) ]]
```

Which, by short-circuit evaluation, the right side of the `&&` is never evaluated and is actually equivalent to this much shorter expression:

```
[[ ! 2 -eq 2 ]]
```

Which will always be false (1).

In short: inside `[[`, the ! affects **parts** of the expression.

## Preferred

Using the `!` inside `[[` is much more common (and portable to more shells (with `[`)), but may be sometimes confusing if not explicitly controlled by judicious use of `()` to delimit the extent of the negation (which might become a problem inside `[` constructs).

But (in bash, ksh and zsh) the result of `! [[` is pretty clearly defined and easier to understand: execute the whole `[[` and negate the result.

Which one should be used is a matter of personal preference (and understanding).

Comment: great answer! shoud become part of abs-guide. Thanks a lot!